# Array is duplicated when pushing an object, it also returned in a proxy in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using **Firebase 9** and **Vue 3** here, and i'm making a chat app with it.
And this is my problem: I'm pushing the message info(objects) to the messages array [], and in the console my array is duplicated like this:

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Array(3)
    0: createdAt: ut {seconds: 1647944143, nanoseconds: 557000000}
    photoURL: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjGXUIFOraxHTZqGIjTLkKGgyM8w7SvVDfF0XQ4=s96-c"
    sender: "Dif Az"
    text: "Test"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
    1: createdAt: ut {seconds: 1647944149, nanoseconds: 756000000}
       photoURL: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjGXUIFOraxHTZqGIjTLkKGgyM8w7SvVDfF0XQ4=s96-c"
       sender: "Dif Az"
       text: "Halo"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
    2: createdAt: ut {seconds: 1647944143, nanoseconds: 557000000}
       photoURL: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjGXUIFOraxHTZqGIjTLkKGgyM8w7SvVDfF0XQ4=s96-c"
       sender: "Dif Az"
       text: "Test"
  [[Prototype]]: Object
  length: 3
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
  [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

And when i submit a new messages in the console, the array is duplicated like on the above, like this, the value of it just like on the first code i include above, it get duplicated:

```
Chat.vue?0d25:56 Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
```

I submit one text and it become this:

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}}
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}}
```

On the data:

```
data() {
  return {
    user: auth.currentUser(),
    msg: '',
    messages: []
  }
}
```

My sendMessage methods:

```
async sendMessage() {
        const messageInfo = {
            userUID: this.user.uid,
            sender: this.user.displayName,
            photoURL: this.user.photoURL,
            text: this.msg,
            createdAt: new Date()
        }
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), {   
                messageInfo
            })
            this.msg = ''
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("Error adding document: " + error.message, error.code)
        }
 },
```

On the mounted:

```
mounted() {
   const messageRef = collection(db, 'messages')

   onSnapshot(messageRef, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            this.messages.push({
                ...doc.data().messageInfo
            })
            console.log(this.messages)
}
```

Ya the array result is like this:

text: 'Test 1'

text: 'Test 2'

text: 'Test 3'

text: 'Test 1'

text: 'Test 2'

text: 'Test 3'

Can you please let me know what I might be doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your `onSnapshot` listener gets called it gets a `QuerySnapshot` with the full data from `messageRef`. So when it gets called a second time, it again contains that full data and not just the changes.

You'll either want to process `snapshot.docChanges`, which only contains the changes, or (simpler) you should clear your `this.messages` when you get called again.

That can be as simple as:

```
onSnapshot(messageRef, (snapshot) => {
  this.messages = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().messageInfo);
})
```